# Infinity loops in react NextJs inside a custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, next.js

Hi i have a customHook inside a service which is been used in page.
i use useRouter to get the query parameter get an infinity loop. I've tried to use useCallBack but even with it doesn't give it still looping.

Service customHook

```
public getUserSkillByUserId(
    userId: string,
    userSkillRequest?: IUserSkillRequest
  ): IFetchHook<IUserSkill | void> {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<HttpError | undefined>(undefined);
    const [data, setData] = useState<IUserSkill>();

    const handleFetch = useCallback(() => {
      if (
        userSkillRequest &&
        userSkillRequest.jobCategoryIdList.every((element) => isNaN(element))
      )
        return;

      setIsLoading(true);
      setError(undefined);
      this.repository
        .getUserSkillByUserId(userId, userSkillRequest)
        .then((response) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e: HttpError) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setError(e);
        });
    }, [userId, userSkillRequest]);

    useEffect(() => {
      handleFetch();
    }, [handleFetch]);

    return { isLoading, error, data };
  }
```

Page

```
const JobDetail = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { query, push } = useRouter();
  const { job_id } = query;
  const jobId = parseInt(job_id as string);

  const USER_ID = 'USERID';
  const JOB_UID = 'JOBID';

  const { data: userSkill, isLoading: userSkillIsLoading } =
    userSkillService.getUserSkillByUserId(USER_ID, {
      uid: JOB_UID,
      jobCategoryIdList: [jobId]
    });


  return (<div> </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue in this code other than how you define the custom hook.

I assume you put the getUserSkillByUserId inside a class or module but in the react documentation it has to be a modular function.

So I would suggest you to use your custom hook like this:

```
function useUserSkill(){
  // all the calculations, fetch etc...
  return {};// custom data;
}

export default useUserSkill;
```

And call it like:

```
function MyComponent(){
  const {} = useUserSkill();
  return (<div />)
}
```

Follow this documentation please. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: + useful link: [Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).